# Cakephp : Sort by a displayed value

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have a table in my view in which one of the columns is returned by a Helper.
How can I sort by this column?

Thanks

**Edit**

```
Controller
$this->set('myArray', $this->paginate('MyModel'));

View
foreach($myArray as $line) {
    echo $line['MyModel']['col1'];
    echo $line['MyModel']['col2'];
    echo $line['MyModel']['col3'];
    echo $line['MyModel']['col4'];
    echo $this->MyModel->someHelper($line['MyModel']['id']);
}
```

I want to sort the table by the $this->MyModel->someHelper($line['MyModel']['id']);

Answer (score 0):

If your data comes via pagination, use.

```
echo $this->Paginator->sort('you_field_name');
```

in your table head.

Comment: No, it doesn't come via pagination. It's a helper that displays it on the view